# When performing a release in maven, what should I do with the pom.xml.releaseBackup and release.properties files?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

When I execute `mvn release:prepare`, I end up with two new files, `release.properties` and `pom.xml.releaseBackup`, and when I execute `mvn release:perform`, those two files do not get removed.

I've read up about the maven release process, and I understand that these files are not removed, and I understand why.

What I can't find out is whether or not those files should be checked in, deleted, or ignored.

Comment: Just do `mvn release:clean` afterwards everything went well. No need to checkin etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, they're not left behind.   I had a problem in my POM, and the release failed.  After fixing the POM and redoing the release, the files disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

You can also run

`mvn release:clean`

To remove any left-over files.